Referential transparency of Jsonnet functions
The Jsonnet Language Reference has this to say about Jsonnet functions:

Functions in Jsonnet are referentially transparent, meaning that any function call can be replaced with its definition, without changing the meaning of the program.

Then why does the following Jsonnet program:
{
    c: local a = function() self.b; {x: a(), b: 'inner'},
    b: 'outer'
}

manifest as follows:
{
   "b": "outer",
   "c": {
      "b": "inner",
      "x": "outer"
   }
}

whereas the following program, which is the same as the first but for replacing the function a by its definition:
{
    c: {x: self.b, b: 'inner'},
    b: 'outer'
}

manifest thus:
{
   "b": "outer",
   "c": {
      "b": "inner",
      "x": "inner"
   }
}

which is different from the manifestation of the first program in the value associated with the x key?

Sounds like the reference is wrong! self breaks referential transparency because what it refers to depends on where in the program it appears. You can also think about this in terms of side effects: every function has the side effect of being able to access the object it appears in, which means that you can't replace a function call with its definition without changing the meaning.

@NaïmFavier The language reference also says: "Jsonnet programs are composed entirely out of expressions. [...] Expressions can be evaluated to produce a value. The evaluation does not have any side effects."

Sounds like it's double wrong!

self is special :)
I think that the issue is that local a = function() self.b; is being immediately/serially evaluated (i.e. no lazy evaluation, as every local), hence it gets that self "collapsed" into its value at that time.
If you want that function to be lazy-evaluated, you'd need to pass such reference, for example (note I dupped the function verbatim for c and cRoot for the sake of just showing the same construct):
foo.jsonnet
{
  c: local a = function(ref) ref.b; { x: a(self), b: 'inner' },
  cRoot: local a = function(ref) ref.b; { x: a($), b: 'inner' },
  b: 'outer',
}

output
{
   "b": "outer",
   "c": {
      "b": "inner",
      "x": "inner"
   },
   "cRoot": {
      "b": "inner",
      "x": "outer"
   }
}


Which expressions are evaluated lazily and which ones immediately?

Evaluation order seems immaterial here as self's referent is defined lexically (as the enclosing JSON object).
